# Rtti method got from Type1 can be invoked on object of Type2

Tags: delphi, rtti

I have the following program.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  var con: TRttiContext;
  var meth := con.GetType(TButton).GetMethod('Click');
  meth.Invoke(BitBtn1, []);
end;
```

`BitBtn1` is a TBitBtn. As you can see, `meth` is a method object got from type `TButton`. But, by my testing, it can be invoked against a TBitBtn without any issue. Is this expected?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? They both inherit from `TCustomButton`, which has a `Click` method.

Comment: @I don't know, as I'm learning this topic. If there is a method defined only on `TButton` and not inherited from `TCustomButton`, it should not be able to be invoked on a TBitBtn, right?

Comment: That's correct, but in your example both inherit from the same ancestor (`TCustomButton`). Your example is like asking "Why do Fred and Debbie both have the same last name 'Wilson'?" when they have the same set of parents. It would be different if you used two classes that didn't share the same ancestor that had the method defined.

Comment: You can see a difference if you use two actually different types, such as `TEdit` and `TMemo`, both of which allow you to enter text. `TMemo` has the property `Lines`, but `TEdit` does not. The code you've written will fail in this case, because there is no ancestry that is shared that has the `Lines` property.

Comment: I've posted an answer that should explain the issue. I wouldn't delete the question, because it might be useful to others in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RTTI you've posted works because both `TBitBtn` and `TButton` share a common ancestor (`TCustomButton`) which implements the `Click` method.

The code would fail if you used two types that didn't descend from an ancestor that implemented the same method, such as `TEdit` and `TMemo`. Both  allow you to enter text, but `TMemo` has the property `Lines`. `TEdit` does not, which would cause the code you've posted to fail.